# Hide next/previous track controls on iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I am using `AVPlayer` to playback a continuous internet radio stream. I set up an `AVAudioSession` and my Info.plist to continue playback while the app is in background, and handle the remote control events to play, pause and stop.

On iOS there are controls for next and previous track in the multitasking bar, in the lock screen, on connected Bluetooth devices and so on. With these controls available and not "grayed out" the user assumes he could skip to another "track". But this is not possible in my scenario. There are no single "tracks". The app can only consume what is played by the icecast server.

**Question**: Is it possible to hide or disable these controls, so the user understands that it is not possible to skip to another "track"? (And if yes, how?)

Comment: avaudioplayer cannot stream music from internet. How are you doing it?

Comment: @BharatGulati My bad, it's an AVPlayer, not AVAudioPlayer. Corrected this in the text.

Comment: So that's not possible since it does not fall under your app. Soory for your dissapointment but Apple does not allow you to change events oustide your app, you can only listen to events if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just don't respond to those controls. Respond only to the controls you *do* respond to (e.g. playpause button).

In this example from one of my apps:

[image]

The "next" and "previous" buttons do nothing; they are meaningless. But I've never gotten a complaint from a user.